# Object Moved error while consuming a webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I've a quick question and request you all  to respond soon.

I've developed a web service with Form based authentication as below.

1.An entry in web.config as below.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">   
    <forms loginUrl="Loginpage.aspx" name=".AuthAspx"></forms>  
</authentication>  
<authorization>   
    <deny users="?"/>  
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Loginpage.aspx" name=".AuthAspx"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/> 
</authorization>
```

2.In Login Page user is validate on button click event as follows.

```
if (txtUserName.Text == "test" && txtPassword.Text == "test")
{
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, // Ticket version
             txtUserName.Text,// Username to be associated with this ticket
             DateTime.Now, // Date/time ticket was issued
             DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50), // Date and time the cookie will expire
             false, // if user has chcked rememebr me then create persistent cookie
             "", // store the user data, in this case roles of the user
             FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath); // Cookie path specified in the web.config file in <Forms> tag if any.

    string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies); // Hashed ticket

    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];

    if (returnUrl == null) returnUrl = "~/Default.aspx";

    Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

3.Webservice has a default webmethod.

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{      
    return "Hello World";            
}
```

4.From a webApplication I am making a call to webservice by creating proxy after adding the webreferance of the above webservice.

```
localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();

service.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential("test", "test");

service.Credentials = credentials;

string hello = service.HelloWorld();

Response.Write(hello);
```

and here while consuming it in a web application the below exception is thrown from webservice proxy.

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="%2fWebService1%2fLoginpage.aspx%3fReturnUrl  %3d%252fWebService1%252fService1.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Could you please share any thoughts to fix it?

Answer (score 6):

You need to set

```
    service.AllowAutoRedirect = true
```

If you are planning to redirect in your code.

Comment: I tried this but it throws an exception - Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'. by displaying viewsource of login page.

Comment: its redirecting you to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this and worked: Go to the website where you are hosting the web service in IIS, click on Session State, change the Cookie Setting's Mode to Use Cookies.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both

```
service.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
service.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```